# How do I tell if an object in my Java array has been selected

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to finish the last iteration of my stickerbook project and I can't figure out these last two components:

- When the user right clicks a sticker, the sticker is deleted
- When the user left clicks on an existing sticker, then clicks elsewhere, the sticker will move to the new location

Here is my sticker selection and sticker placement code in the `Main`. I'm trying to do something where if I right click an existing sticker, the `slot` variable will equal the slot of the object selected then use a `switch` command to delete which ever `slot` index was selected. I don't know how to approach the second bullet.

```
    //Create a Sticker array called stickerArr that holds 10 stickers
    Sticker[] stickerArr = new Sticker[10];
    //Declare integer variables called xClick and yClick
    //Declare integer variables called slot and choosePic and make them equal to 0
    int slot = 0;
    int xClick, yClick;
    int choosePic = 0;

    while(true) { //start infinite while loop that executes everything within the loop
        xClick = EZInteraction.getXMouse();
        yClick = EZInteraction.getYMouse();
        //Start an if statement to select the appropriate picture
        //A different integer is set to choosePic so that we can place the selected picture later
        if (EZInteraction.wasMouseLeftButtonPressed()) { //start the sticker selection if-statement
            if (dolphin.isPointInElement(xClick, yClick)){
                choosePic = 1;
                sound1.play();
            }
            else if (fish.isPointInElement(xClick, yClick)){
                choosePic = 2;
                sound2.play();
            }
            else if (shark.isPointInElement(xClick, yClick)) {
                choosePic = 3;
                sound3.play();
            }
            else if (jellyfish.isPointInElement(xClick, yClick)) {
                choosePic = 4;
                sound4.play();
            }

        //Only execute if the background (fishbowl picture) is under the mouse.
        while(fishbowl.isPointInElement(xClick, yClick)){ // start fishbowl-while
            xClick = EZInteraction.getXMouse();
            yClick = EZInteraction.getYMouse();

            if(EZInteraction.wasMouseLeftButtonPressed()) { //start choosePic-if
                //Start a switch statement for choosePic
                //Whatever picture was selected will decide what sticker object is placed on the canvas
                //Each sticker object will have an image name, a sound, and an x and y coordinate to be used for the save load function
                switch(choosePic) { //start switch
                    case 1: stickerArr[slot] = new Sticker("dolphin.png", "sound1.wav", xClick, yClick);
                        sound1.play();
                        slot++;
                        break;
                    case 2: stickerArr[slot] = new Sticker("fish.png", "sound2.wav", xClick, yClick);
                        sound2.play();
                        slot++;
                        break;
                    case 3: stickerArr[slot] = new Sticker("shark.png", "sound3.wav", xClick, yClick);
                        sound3.play();
                        slot++;
                        break;
                    case 4: stickerArr[slot] = new Sticker("jellyfish.png", "sound4.wav", xClick, yClick);
                        sound4.play();
                        slot++;
                        break;  
                    default:  // do nothing
                        break;
                } // end switch
            }// end choosePic-if

            if(EZInteraction.wasMouseRightButtonPressed()){
                slot = ???; // I'm trying to set 'slot' to whichever index was selected when the user clicks on any existing sticker on the canvas
                switch(slot) { //for whatever slot was selected, the objects information will be deleted and cleared from the txt file
                    case 1: break;
                    case 2: break;
                    case 3: break;
                    case 4: break;
                    case 5: break;
                    case 6: break;
                    case 7: break;
                    case 8: break;
                    case 9: break;
                    case 10: break;
                }
            }
        } // end fishbowl-while

        //Refresh screen
        EZ.refreshScreen();
    } //end infinite while
```

If it helps, here is my class and it's methods.

```
public class Sticker {

    public int x, y;
    public EZImage picture;
    public EZSound sounds;
    public String picName;

    Sticker(String image, String sound, int xPosition, int yPosition){
        picture = EZ.addImage(image, xPosition, yPosition);
        sounds = EZ.addSound(sound);
        x = xPosition;
        y = yPosition;
        picName = image;
    }

    Sticker(String name, int somex, int somey){
        picture = EZ.addImage(name, somex, somey);
        x = somex;
        y = somey;
    }
}
```

This is a portion of my entire code. I didn't think it was important for everything to be shown.

Summary of program: Creates an interactive mock-stickerbook where left clicking on a picture on a palette selects an image and then left clicking on the canvas/background places that sticker object. Each sticker object has it's own set of information (image name, sound, x, and y). This information will be used in an already implemented save, load, and clear function. The above two points, are all that is left to implement.

Comment: It would be helpful if you better explained your intention.

You have plenty of comments in your code, but unfortunately, they comment on the various common java structures used, and not the reasoning or *intent* as to *why* they're used. Comments like `// end choosePic-if`, `//do nothing`, `//Create a Sticker array called stickerArr that holds 10 stickers`, etc. don't explain anything novel about the code they represent. I can already easily see the sticker array has size 10, for example, but I have no idea what the intention is behind having such an array in the first place

Comment: Remember, the goal of comments isn't to paraphrase your `Java` code into some hacked up English. It's to explain to the reader of your code why your code does what it does. You're not trying to explain to them the fundamentals of how an if statement is opened or closed. That's up to the read to know already.

Comment: @AMomchilov thanks for clarifying that for me. Well the purpose is to create a mock-stickerbook that uses an array to store and hold information. the comments that start with 'start' or 'end' are just markers for me to identify where pieces of my code are (i,e where something starts or ends). I'll edit my question to better explain what I want